# How to subclass OrderedDict so its items can be accessed like attributes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I would like to have a subclass of `OrderedDict` that can access items through attributes. The following code works properly in python 3.7, but in python 2.7 it gets stuck in recursion.

Is there any way for this to work  in both python 2.7 and 3.7?

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

class myDict(OrderedDict):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self.keys():
            return self.__getitem__(key)
        return super(myDict, self).__getattribute__(key)

d = myDict()
d['hello'] = 'world'
print(d.hello)
```

Comment: I guess the problem is the call to `self.keys()` which agains calls `self.__attr__`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the call to `self.keys()`, which again triggers `__getattr__`. Instead, you could just `try` to access the key and call `super` if that fails:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    try:
        return self[key]
    except KeyError:
        return super(myDict, self).__getattr__(key)
```

Should work for both versions and both keys and attributes, printing `d.hello` and `d.keys()`:

```
$ python2 test.py 
world
['hello']
$ python3 test.py 
world
odict_keys(['hello'])
```